# How do I include a variable in an annotation?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've added an annotation to a figure and no issues with just addind the text but I'd like to add the result of a variable in after the text?

I've tried a few variations of placing the variable but keep getting a syntax error.

```
pct_inc_m = (plotm11/plotm0-1) * 100

axs.annotate('The percentage increase for males for this period is (pct_inc_m'), xy=(0.01, 0.89), xycoords='axes fraction')
```

removing the variable within the .annotate lets the code run fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a SyntaxError because your quotes are mismatched.

```
axs.annotate('The percentage increase for males for this period is (pct_inc_m)', xy=(0.01, 0.89), xycoords='axes fraction')
                                                                             ^^
```

Though presumably you want the value of the variable to be displayed:

```
axs.annotate('The percentage increase for males for this period is ({})'.format(pct_inc_m), xy=(0.01, 0.89), xycoords='axes fraction')
```

Comment: I was looking up .format but wasn't sure how to use it. Thank you!